# Using ngInclude multiple times in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have this little script and the controller in angular is completely empty so nothing there.

My question is why can't I run to ngIncludes (By the way no errors)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height    attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="main">
<ng-include src="'templates/android/header.html'" />
<ng-include src="'templates/android/newsfeed.html'" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can start by removing the single quotes on your "src"'s.

Comment: That would not be a good idea, since that makes sure it is a string in the js parser.

Comment: Can you reproduce that issue in Fiddle/Planker?

Comment: And I would try: `<div  ng-include="templates/android/header.html'"></div>`

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem, but in my case I didn't close the div tag properly:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/agendar.html'">
<div ng-include="'partials/atendimento.html'">
```

As I saw you do that, but you're using the 'ng-include' as tag. Try like this (worked perfectly for me). Be sure your angular is updated and then use only 'ng-include' (no 'data-'):

```
<div ng-include="'partials/agendar.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'partials/atendimento.html'"></div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had found an example with self-closing div tags like <div ng-include="'path.html'" />, but the second div would not show until I changed them to use separate closing tags: <div ng-include="'path.html'"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Can you start without src attribute like this:

if you give this type it doesn't show any error messages ngInclude the attribute binding so it doesn't show any error messages.

```
<data-ng-include="'templates/android/header.html'" />
<data-ng-include="'templates/android/newsfeed.html'" />
```

The correct way is this:

```
<div data-ng-include="'templates/android/header.html'"></div>
<div data-ng-include="'templates/android/newsfeed.html'"></div>
```

Comment: I just tried your example and it returned the first include. For the second one the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null`

Comment: You don't use src attribute in ngInclude. ngInclude like as src attribute

Comment: I just edited my own text, since I did stupid typo's. But It still write that error then.

Comment: No it still doesn't work If I am using it with W3 appliant syntax I will get the earlier mentioned error, if not it doesn't return any errors, but in both cases only show the first include.

Comment: I done it both the included items will show in my site it doesn't show any errors...

Comment: Friend can you please send your project folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer valid HTML and suggest you:

```
<div data-ng-include="'templates/android/header.html'"></div>
<div data-ng-include="'templates/android/newsfeed.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Your example does not return any errors, but only returns the first include and then I am back to scratch. In general my issue is that I can't do more than one include (the next simply doesn't show up). Sorry if I wasn't exactly clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the question is not so clear for me but I tried like this and it worked correctly:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <div ng-include src='"file1.html"'></div>
     <div ng-include src='"file2.html"'></div>
  </body>
```

[Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/dvzQVeC9Rzf0SJRk0fq5/preview)